# Outlook can't connect to exchange, but via vpn it works

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook, vpn, exchange

hello i have some trouble with my outlook.It cant connect to our exchange server, but when i activate vpn it works. All the other users doesn't have this problem.

could you help me please?

Comment: This sounds like a configuration problem ( or intentional ) on the server side of things.

Comment: This sounds like a configuration issue with your laptop.

Comment: I Know but which configuration

Answer (score 0):

This clearly appears to be some sort of network configuration error. Here are the most likely candidates.

1) Your Outlook is configured to look for the exchange server by local name (http://exchange01 - for instance) and, when you are not on the VPN it looks for exchange01 (the pretend hostname of exchange in this case) and finds nothing. When you are on the VPN, since it bridges your network to the same network as Exchange most likely, you are then able to see exchange01 as a host and connect to it. I would compare your outlook mailbox settings to that of another employee's

2) Your other coworkers are also on the VPN when using outlook (perhaps things are configured at your location so that Outlook can only connect when in the office or over the VPN)

3) You are on the wrong internal network. Are you connected to the same wifi or wired network as your coworkers? This can happen if you end up on the guest wireless network or are plugged in to an ethernet port which is on a separate VLAN from your production network.

Let me know if you need further assistance with this!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found the following solution.

Press the Windows button/key/icon and type 'Identify' and open 'Identity and repair network problems'. After running this I got the message `The proxy server isn’t responding`.

The long detailed fix is described [here](https://malwaretips.com/blogs/the-proxy-server-isnt-responding-removal/).
These are the steps for the quick fix:

- Press the Windows button/key/icon and type and open 'Internet options'
- Go to the 'Connections' tab
- Open 'LAN Settings'
- Disable 'Use a proxy server for your LAN'

This could be one of the causes for the problem, I hope it helps!